# What do I do with a sandworm scale?

Tags: starlink

I've started Starlink and discovered a sandworm tunneling around the planet. Upon pulling it up, it dropped a scale, which I can pick up, but it's just held (similar to the elemental canisters). Also, the worm now chases me all over the planet, trying to hit me and make me drop the scale.

Is there something I can do with this scale?  Am I supposed to take it somewhere? I've tried taking it back to the crashed ship, but nothing seems to be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scale can be turned in at the observatory.

[image]

Here's the location on the map

[image]

Taking items here seems to level up the location, giving additional benefits.  There may be several places like this, so check the map to see where you can take the different kinds of items.